# Login to router using CURL

Tags: php, curl, router, http-authentication

I am trying to auto login and restart my router automatically using PHP with the help of CURL, but it always return "Protected Object" even the user and password are correct. The script was tested from local host and there is no firewall:

```
<?php
$host = "192.168.1.250";
$user = "reboot";
$pass = "default";
$timeout = 10;
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pass);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$host."/restart.html");
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $data; // always return "Protected Object"

?>
```

Comment: What is the content of `$data`?

Comment: @Dai "Protected Object".

Comment: @Dai Is there some thing I should add to my question?

Comment: Have you compared the HTTP request you're making with the HTTP request coming from your browser? Have you used a tool like Fiddler? http://fiddler2.com/